# Keeping a PHP variable throughout several HTML pages/stages

Tags: php, html, object-persistence

I'm getting that the variable `$email` is undefined. I know that the `emailParser()` method works as it does everything it's supposed to do.

How to I make it so that the variable $email persists so that I can access it in the second iteration of index.php?

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    include "etext.php";
    //Run etext

    $email = emailParser($message); //set by running etext


    header("Location: index.php?status=submitted");
    exit;
}

?>

<h1>Etext Email Converter</h1>

<?php
if (isset($_GET["status"]) AND $_GET["status"] == "submitted") {
    $output_file_path = $email->generateParsedEmailFile();

 ?>
    <p> File located at: <?php echo $output_file_path; ?> </p><br>
    <a href=<?php echo $output_file_path;?> >Click Here to Access</a>
<?php
 } else { ?>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <label for"message"></label>
        <textArea rows="30" cols="40" name="message" id="message"></textArea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Did you try `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: No, I'm an HTML/PHP newbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **$_SESSION** super-global to achieve this.

```
$_SESSION['Email'] = 'example@example.com';
```

That would make that variable accessible on multiple pages **provided you support sessions within your code**.

To do that, on every page you want to access the session values you would call

```
session_start();
```

and after you have called that, you can go ahead and access the variable you set elsewhere.

```
echo $_SESSION['Email']; // Outputs example@example.com
```

Comment: Do not forget to start a session with session_start()